# Syslog File Size Limit

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, syslog, busybox, logrotate

I have a yocto image using syslog and logrotate. My syslog allows two log files to be created. One for debug messages, one for all other messages. My debug log file will grow to 200kb then will be moved to debug.0. Archive files such as debug.1, debug.2 etc are never created. This means I am loosing data. I set my logrotate for this file to activate daily and at a size of 10MB.

Where does syslog set the max file size of a log file? In my build my `syslog.conf` is installed from the `busyboxappend.bb` and contains

```
#  /etc/syslog.conf     Configuration file for busybox's syslogd utility

*.debug     /home/root/.evcc_logs/debug

*.info      /var/log/info
*.info      /dev/console
```

busybox.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://evcc_kernel_features.cfg file://syslog.conf"

do_deploy() {
    install -d ${D}/etc/
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/syslog.conf ${D}/etc/
}   
addtask deploy after do_install 

do_install_append () {
   install -d ${D}/home/root/.evcc_logs/
   install -d ${D}/etc/evcc/
   install -d ${D}/tmpfs/
   install -d ${D}/tmpfs/can
}
FILES_${PN} += "/home/root/.evcc_logs/ \
                /etc/evcc/ \
                /tmpfs/ \
                /tmpfs/can \
                "
```

logrotate.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files/:"
SRC_URI_append = " file://logrotate.conf file://services file://rotaterules"

inherit systemd

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = " logrotate.service logrotate.timer"

do_install_append(){
    install -d 755 ${D}/${sysconfdir}/logrotate.d/
        
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/logrotate.conf ${D}/etc
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/rotaterules/info ${D}/etc/logrotate.d/info
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/rotaterules/debug ${D}/etc/logrotate.d/debug
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/rotaterules/btmp ${D}/etc/logrotate.d/btmp
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/rotaterules/wtmp ${D}/etc/logrotate.d/wtmp   
    
    install -d ${D}{systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/services/logrotate.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/services/logrotate.timer ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
}

FILES_${PN} += " \
    /etc/logrotate.conf \
    ${base_libdir}/systemd/system/logrotate.service \
    ${base_libdir}/systemd/system/logrotate.timer \
    /lib/systemd/system \
    "
```

logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# compress log files
compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

logrotate.timer (set to run every minute for debug)

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer to run log rotation every day
Requires=logrotate.service

[Timer]
Unit=logrotate.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

logrotate.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Log rotation service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Edit: I thought my system may have an inherent max file size that I was not aware of. This does not appear to be a feature.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a misconfiguration issue in busybox. I had to go into the logging settings and turn off the rotate logfile option. I also increased the syslogd read buffer size.

```
# CONFIG_FEATURE_ROTATE_LOGFILE is not set
CONFIG_FEATURE_SYSLOGD_READ_BUFFER_SIZE=512
```